# How to send trace data to Jaeger through OpenTelemetry in front end app?

Tags: javascript, docker, zipkin, jaeger, open-telemetry

## Background

I am trying to trace in a front end app.

I am not be able to use [@opentelemetry/exporter-jaeger](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js/tree/master/packages/opentelemetry-exporter-jaeger) since [I believe it is for Node.js back end app only](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-js/issues/1433).

So I am trying to use [@opentelemetry/exporter-collector](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector).

## 1. Succeed to print in browser console

First I tried to print the trace data in the browser console. And
the code below succeed printing the trace data.

```
import { CollectorTraceExporter } from '@opentelemetry/exporter-collector';
import { DocumentLoad } from '@opentelemetry/plugin-document-load';
import { SimpleSpanProcessor, ConsoleSpanExporter } from '@opentelemetry/tracing';
import { WebTracerProvider } from '@opentelemetry/web';

const provider = new WebTracerProvider({ plugins: [new DocumentLoad()] });
provider.addSpanProcessor(new SimpleSpanProcessor(new ConsoleSpanExporter()));
provider.register();
```

## 2. Failed to forward to Jaeger

Now I want to forward them to Jaeger.

I am running [Jaeger all-in-one](https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.18/getting-started/#all-in-one) by

```
docker run -d --name jaeger \
  -e COLLECTOR_ZIPKIN_HTTP_PORT=9411 \
  -p 5775:5775/udp \
  -p 6831:6831/udp \
  -p 6832:6832/udp \
  -p 5778:5778 \
  -p 16686:16686 \
  -p 14268:14268 \
  -p 9411:9411 \
  jaegertracing/all-in-one:1.18
```

Based on the [Jaeger port document](https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.18/getting-started/#all-in-one), I might be able to use these two ports (if other ports work, that will be great too!):

```
14250   HTTP    collector   accept model.proto
9411    HTTP    collector   Zipkin compatible endpoint (optional)
```

Then I further found [more info about this port](https://www.jaegertracing.io/docs/1.18/apis/#zipkin-formats-stable):

> Zipkin Formats (stable)
>
> Jaeger Collector can also accept spans in several Zipkin data format,
> namely JSON v1/v2 and Thrift. The Collector needs to be configured to
> enable Zipkin HTTP server, e.g. on port 9411 used by Zipkin
> collectors. The server enables two endpoints that expect POST
> requests:
>
> ```
> /api/v1/spans for submitting spans in Zipkin JSON v1 or Zipkin Thrift format.
> /api/v2/spans for submitting spans in Zipkin JSON v2.
> ```

I updated my codes to

```
import { CollectorTraceExporter, CollectorProtocolNode } from '@opentelemetry/exporter-collector';
import { DocumentLoad } from '@opentelemetry/plugin-document-load';
import { SimpleSpanProcessor } from '@opentelemetry/tracing';
import { WebTracerProvider } from '@opentelemetry/web';

const provider = new WebTracerProvider({ plugins: [new DocumentLoad()] });

// The config below currently has issue
const exporter = new CollectorTraceExporter({
    serviceName: 'my-service',
    protocolNode: CollectorProtocolNode.HTTP_JSON,
    url: 'http://localhost:9411/api/v1/spans', // Also tried v2
});

provider.addSpanProcessor(new SimpleSpanProcessor(exporter));
provider.register();
```

However, I got bad request for both v1 and v2 endpoints without any response body returned

> POST http://localhost:9411/api/v1/spans 400 (Bad Request)
>
> POST http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans 400 (Bad Request)

Any idea how can I make the request format correct? Thanks

## UPDATE (8/19/2020)

I think Andrew is right that I should use OpenTelemetry collector. I also got some help from Valentin Marchaud and Deniz Gurkaynak
at Gitter. Just add the link here for further people who meet same issue:
https://gitter.im/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-node?at=5f3aa9481226fc21335ce61a

My final working solution posted at https://stackoverflow.com/a/63489195/2000548

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thing is, you should use opentelemetry collector if you use opentelemetry exporter.

Pls see schema in attachment [image]

Also I created a gist, which will help you to setup
pls see

https://gist.github.com/AndrewGrachov/11a18bc7268e43f1a36960d630a0838f

(just tune the values, export to jaeger-all-in-one instead of separate + cassandra, etc)

Comment: Thanks Andrew! Just want to confirm, based on this chart, do you mean I need an OpenTelemetry collector between my front end app and Jaeger collector?

Comment: yep, otel collector is no-brainer - one stop shop for all your needs.
Even jaeger creators move for it

https://medium.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-embraces-opentelemetry-collector-90a545cbc24

Comment: I would you assume you are referring https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector, it is a lot of info. I will take some time trying it and report back. Thanks again!

Comment: To save some time for future people, my final working solution posted at https://stackoverflow.com/a/63489195/2000548